# Boost library iostream::copy not working

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    ifstream file("gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(bzip2_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed Boost as in this question: 
[How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010) ?

And I get error on the `boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout)` statement.

I'm very new to Boost so I don't know if this code is right or wrong.

I think I did every thing what I should do, and I'm lost.

---

**EDIT**

I have checked this question: [exceptions from boost::iostreams::copy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167109/exceptions-from-boostiostreamscopy) .

And I have changed my test code to know what error does I get.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    try {
        ifstream file("hello.bz2", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
        filtering_streambuf<input> in;
        in.push(bzip2_decompressor());
        in.push(file);
        boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
    }
    catch(const bzip2_error& exception) {
        int error = exception.error();

        if(error == boost::iostreams::bzip2::data_error) {
            // compressed data stream is corrupted
            cout << "compressed data stream is corrupted";
        }
        else if(error == boost::iostreams::bzip2::data_error_magic)
        {
            // compressed data stream does not begin with the 'magic' sequence 'B' 'Z' 'h'
            cout << "compressed data stream does not begin with the 'magic' sequence 'B' 'Z' 'h'";
        }
        else if(boost::iostreams::bzip2::config_error) {
            // libbzip2 has been improperly configured for the current platform
            cout << "libbzip2 has been improperly configured for the current platform";
        }
    }
}
```

It says I get `boost::iostreams::bzip2::config_error`.

Does this mean I installed bzip2 filter wrong???

Because I get some error what I used

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 -sBZIP2_SOURCE="C:\bzip2-1.0.6" --build-type=complete stage
```

I get:

```
C:\boost_1_54_0>b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 -sBZIP2_SOURCE="C:\bzip2-1.0.6" --build-t
ype=complete stage
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached)
    - iconv (separate)         : no  (cached)
    - icu                      : no  (cached)
    - icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
    - message-compiler         : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : no  (cached)
    - gcc visibility           : no  (cached)
    - long double support      : yes (cached)
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <thre
ading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <th
reading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : building
    - chrono                   : building
    - context                  : building
    - coroutine                : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : building
    - iostreams                : building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - signals                  : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - wave                     : building

...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 47439 targets...

C:\boost_1_54_0>b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 -sBZIP2_SOURCE="C:\bzip2-1.0.6" --build-type=complete stage
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached)
    - iconv (separate)         : no  (cached)
    - icu                      : no  (cached)
    - icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
    - message-compiler         : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : no  (cached)
    - gcc visibility           : no  (cached)
    - long double support      : yes (cached)
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : building
    - chrono                   : building
    - context                  : building
    - coroutine                : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : building
    - iostreams                : building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - signals                  : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - wave                     : building

...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 47439 targets...
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It would help us hugely if you included the error, but I suspect this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3167109/78845

Comment: I get "Unhandled exception at 0x777015de in CTest1.exe: Microsoft c++ exception: boost::Exception_detail:clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostream::bzip2_error> > at memro location 0x0036f6c0.."  No idea what it is...:(

Comment: yup, your answer is in the question linked by Johnsyweb

Comment: @nijansen I get error on boost::iostreams::bzip2::config_error. How do I fix it? :( I have asked another question on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122454/installing-bzip2-filter-on-windows is the link. maybe I did something wrong while installing

Comment: "I get error" doesn't help us to help you. You need to tell us what the error is! Is it at compile-time, link-time or run-time? What does it say?

Comment: I'v updated my error @Johnsyweb. Please help me T_T

Comment: I get error on runtime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is actually misleading.

This is because:

```
if(boost::iostreams::bzip2::config_error)
```

...always evaluates to non-zero and gives you the wrong error message!

I don't have a Windows PC available to me, but I tested "your" code on a Mac (Boost installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)), and got the same error.

```
libbzip2 has been improperly configured for the current platform
```

And so I fixed that up and added some error checking:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    char filename[] = "gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2";

    if (!boost::filesystem::exists(filename))
    { 
        cout << "Can't find " << filename << ". Expect errors to follow! " << endl;
    } 

    ifstream file(filename, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(bzip2_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    try
    { 
        boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
    } 
    catch (const bzip2_error& exception) 
    { 
        cout << exception.what() << endl;

        int error = exception.error();
        if (error == bzip2::data_error)
        { 
            cout << "compressed data stream is corrupted";
        } 
        else if (error == bzip2::data_error_magic)
        { 
            cout << "compressed data stream does not begin with the 'magic' sequence 'B' 'Z' 'h'";
        } 
        else if (error == bzip2::config_error) 
        {
            cout << "libbzip2 has been improperly configured for the current platform";
        } 
        else
        { 
            cout << "Error: " << error;
        } 
        cout << endl;
    } 
}
```

#### Build

```
> clang++ 18121908.cpp -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o 18121908
```

#### Run

```
> ./18121908 
Can't find gcc-4.7.2.tar.bz2. Expect errors to follow! 
bzip2 error
Error: -7
```

Why `-7`? Because `#define BZ_UNEXPECTED_EOF    (-7)`. Boost calls this `bzip2::unexpected_eof`. You've unexpectedly hit the end of the *stream*!

#### Make a valid (if questionable) bzip2 file:

```
> echo 'There should be some compiler stuff in here' > gcc-4.7.2.tar
> bzip2 gcc-4.7.2.tar
```

#### Re-run

```
> ./18121908 
There should be some compiler stuff in here
```

### Conclusion

You need to check whether the file exists before attempting to decompress it.

Comment: Oh my god I was so stupid. I forgot that on visual studio if you do ctrl + f5 the current work directory was where the actual source file is. Thank you so much @Johnsyweb